# Can anyone tell me why the result is like this

Tags: go

```
import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    Queue []string
}

func main() {

    myStruct := &MyStruct{}
    // Pre-allocate a slice with a capacity of 5
    queue := make([]string, 0, 5)

    myStruct.Queue = queue

    // Add elements to the "end" of the queue
    myStruct.Queue = append(myStruct.Queue, "1")
    myStruct.Queue = append(myStruct.Queue, "2")
    myStruct.Queue = append(myStruct.Queue, "3")

    // queue: [1 2 3]
    fmt.Println(myStruct.Queue)
    fmt.Println(queue)

    // Add another element
    queue = append(queue, "4")
    fmt.Println(queue)

    queue = append(queue, "5")
    fmt.Println(queue)

    // queue: [1 2 3] ? or [1 2 3 4 5] ?
    fmt.Println(myStruct.Queue)
    // [ 4 5 3 ]
}
```

I expected [1,2,3] or [1,2,3,4,5] but, its [4, 5, 3]
when I changed Capacity of []string as 0, it was [1 ,2, 3]. because its reference pointer address change ([]string length > capacity).

by the way, I don't understand what its [4, 5, 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
queue := make([]string, 0, 5)
```

Makes an anonymous array with a size of 5, and creates the slice `queue` that points to the beginning of that array, has a capacity of 5, and a length of 0.

```
myStruct.Queue = queue
```

*Copies* the slice-header `queue` into `myStruct.Queue`. `myStruct.Queue` now points to the beginning of the same array, has a capacity of 5, and a length of 0.

```
myStruct.Queue = append(myStruct.Queue, "1")
myStruct.Queue = append(myStruct.Queue, "2")
myStruct.Queue = append(myStruct.Queue, "3")
```

Appends three elements to `myStruct.Queue`. Since space is available, these elements are inserted into the existing array, which now contains `["1" "2" "3" "" ""]`. `myStruct.Queue`'s length is now 3. `queue` still points to the same array, but its length is still 0.

```
queue = append(queue, "4")
queue = append(queue, "5")
```

Appends two elements to `queue`. Space is available in the backing array, and `queue` has a length of zero, so these two elements are inserted into the *first two* indices of the array, overwriting `"1"` and `"2"`.

Now the array contains `["4" "5" "3" "" ""]`. `queue` is a view into that array with a length of 2, so it contains `["4" "5"]`. `myStruct.Queue` is a view into the same array with a length of 3, so it contains `["4" "5" "3"]`.